# Circuit analysis problem involving Fourier series

Tags: circuit-analysis, fourier, laplace-transform

**Please help me with this problem**

I can not solve this. It is about Fourier series. It is so hard.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Show what you have already tried. (Approach and mathematics.)

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but I can not figure how it works. I tried fourier. I do not know how to go on

Comment: **What** have you done?  Show it to us.  The rules on homework here are that you show what you've done and where you got stuck.  People will then give you hints as to how you can solve it.  No one will give you the complete answer.

Comment: Did you find the transfer function of the LR filter? Do you know or look up the Fourier series of square pulses? Please add both details to the question.